# Proof of dimension of Polyhedron

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, convex-geometry, polyhedra

[image]
[image]

---

Before proving the theorem the book introduces a new definition called implicit equality.
What does exactly the below equality mean?
$$
A^{=}x=b^{=}
$$
What is inside this set? 
$$
\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \colon A^{=}x = b^{=}\}
$$
I encountered this notation in Michele Conforti, Integer Programming Book, published by Springer

Comment: Please, to provide necessary context, include in your post: the title of the book, the author, the edition, and year of publication.

Comment: If my last comment seemed too involved, *Where did you encounter this notation?*

Comment: @amWhy I have added the reference inside the post.

Comment: Thanks for the edit!  That will help answerers to help you!

Comment: The equality means you take the rows containing implicit equalities and consider the set defined by replacing those inequalities by actual equalities.

Answer (score 2):

The book first defines within the n-dimensional space of consideration an included subspace, which is defined by all *equalities* out of $Ax ≤ b$ (which as subsytem gets denoted by $A^= x = b^=$). This is the space where the polytope, being then defined therein by the *inequalities* out of $Ax ≤ b$ (which as subsytem gets denoted by $A^< x ≤ b^<$), truely lives.

Consider this example: try to describe the triangle with vertices $(0,0,0)$, $(1,0,0)$, and $(0,1,0)$. I.e. a 2D polygon being described within a 3D space. It is defined by the system $x≥0$, $y≥0$, $x+y≤1$, and $z=0$. Here the first 3 relations are the defining inequalities *within the subspace* defined by the fourth relation.

--- rk